# Is it possible to sort a dynamic array with strings in Iron python?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, spotfire

I am writing a iron python code in spotfire to pull data from a data table based on demand, by passing existing data table filters. The thing is user wants to sort the values in a particular sorted order specified by them.
Here is the problem: if we have whole data table, we are able to sort the values in the row by going through the column properties -> sort order -> custom sort order and arrange them. But right now we don't have complete values so how can we handle it in the iron python script or spotfire.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar work around for sorting number values as strings.

My recommendation is to make a Calculated column that adds spaces before your actual string, based on how you want to order it.  In Spotfire visualizations, it trims the strings so that the user doesn't see it misaligned, and everything was sorted accordingly.

If this is a simple task, it can be done directly in the expression for the calculated column.

My example:

```
If([AR Days]<>"(PA)",
If(Integer([AR Days])>360,">360",
If(Integer([AR Days])>359," " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>349,"  " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>339,"   " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>329,"    " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>319,"     " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>309,"      " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>299,"       " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>289,"        " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>279,"         " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>269,"          " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>259,"           " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>249,"            " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>239,"             " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>229,"              " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>219,"               " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>209,"                " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>199,"                 " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>189,"                  " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>179,"                   " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>169,"                    " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>159,"                     " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>149,"                      " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>139,"                       " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>129,"                        " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>119,"                         " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>109,"                          " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>99,"                           " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>89,"                            " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>79,"                             " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>69,"                              " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>59,"                               " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>49,"                                " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>39,"                                 " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>29,"                                  " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>19,"                                   " & [AR Days],
If(Integer([AR Days])>9,"                                    " & [AR Days],
                          "                                     " & [AR Days]))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))),
                          "                                      (PA)")
```

For my more complicated example, I allowed the user to select custom size groupings for a similar bucket, with a hard upper limit of 360+ being the final bucket.  This value was an integer in a text entry box (Property called udBucketSize), and the Script on change was the following:

```
bck = Document.Properties["udBucketSize"]
if bck < 10:
    x = 'If([ACCOUNT LOCATION (2)]="1","                                     (PA)",'
else:
    x = 'If([ACCOUNT LOCATION (2)]="1","    (PA)",'
y = ')'
oldbck = 0
if bck == 1:
    x = "[AR Days Workaround]"
else:
    while oldbck + bck < 360 and bck > 0:
        if oldbck == 0:
            x += 'If(DateDiff("day",[FINAL BILL DATE],[SNAPSHOTDATE])<=' + str(oldbck + bck) + ',"'
        else:
            x += 'If(DateDiff("day",[FINAL BILL DATE],[SNAPSHOTDATE])<=' + str(oldbck + bck - 1) + ',"'
        if bck < 10:
            z = (360 - oldbck)/10 + 1
            n = 1
            while n <= z:
                x += ' '
                n += 1
        else:
            if oldbck < 100:
                x+= '    '
            elif oldbck < 200:
                x+= '   '
            elif oldbck < 300:
                x+= '  '
            else:
                x+= ' '
        if oldbck == 0:
            x+= str(oldbck)  + '-' + str(oldbck+bck) +'",'
            oldbck += 1
        else:
            x+= str(oldbck)  + '-' + str(oldbck+bck - 1) +'",'
        y+= ')'
        oldbck += bck

    x += 'If(DateDiff("day",[FINAL BILL DATE],[SNAPSHOTDATE])<=360," ' + str(oldbck) + '-360", ">360")' + y
    print x
Document.Properties["udBucketString"] = x
```

The Property udBucketString was then the expression for my calculated column, which is now sorted the way I wanted it to be.

Similar methodologies can be used to sort letters or special characters.